# Install Qt4 on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, qt4, macos-big-sur

I want to install qt4 on my mac, but whenever I type in `brew install qt@4` I get the error

```
x86_64cpuid.s:273:7: error: invalid token in expression
cmpq $0,%rax
     ^
x86_64cpuid.s:273:7: error: invalid operand
cmpq $0,%rax
     ^
x86_64cpuid.s:274:9: error: invalid token in expression
cmoveq %rcx,%rax
       ^
x86_64cpuid.s:274:9: error: invalid operand
cmoveq %rcx,%rax
       ^
```

I tried brew install openssl@1.0 and got the same errors.

I tried to follow this instructions [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/install-mac.html) from the Qt doc, but I get two errors while running `make`.

```
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_powerpc.h:126:36: error:
    invalid output constraint '=&b' in asm
             : [originalValue] "=&b" (originalValue),
                               ^

../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_powerpc.h:143:36: error:
    invalid output constraint '=&b' in asm
             : [originalValue] "=&b" (originalValue),
                               ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From filename qatomic_powerpc.h I can guess that it tries to build powerpc binaries, while that architecture has been dropped since 10.6 ‘Snow Leopard’.

While I imagine it is possible to patch Qt 4 sources to make it buildable on Big Sur, I'd like to ask what do you need it for? Most likely a better approach is to port the code to Qt 5.15.2.

Note there is a resolved bug report about that: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/61886